# How to draw a binary tree in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, data-structures, javafx-2, binary-tree

I have to represesent the structure of a binary tree in a JavaFXML Aplication. I read about Canvas, but i don't have any idea about it.

I need something like this in my program:
[This is the result that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saDi0.png)

I need that the values of a Node appear within a shape, but in the correct place

Can someone help me with it? 
Any idea is helpful for me.

Comment: A quick Google search gave [this Github repo](https://github.com/EricCanull/fxbinarytree). Have you checked it out?

Comment: @Antonio You are supposed to use it, not to decode it and reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void drawNodeRecursive(int x1,int y1,int x,int y,Node node){
    Line line = new Line(x1, y1+5, x, y);
    drawField.getChildren().add(line);
    Circle circle = new Circle(x,y, 15, Paint.valueOf("blue"));
    drawField.getChildren().add(circle);
    Text txt = new Text(x-3,y+3, String.valueOf(node.value));
    drawField.getChildren().add(txt);
    if(node.left != null)
        nodeRecursive(x,y,x-(30),y+30,node.left);
    if(node.right != null)
        nodeRecursive(x,y,x+(30),y+30,node.right);
}
```

Just use a recursive Method to draw this Nodes

drawField is just a simple Pane